# view command before build code in Cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm newbie in Cmake. I always use `SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to view `-I ..` `-D..` or other options (for example `-lpthread, -ldl,` ...). I don't know have any way to view this options before run make (build code). Anyone can guide how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `make VERBOSE=1`? Or `make VERBOSE=1 -n` which doesn't execute commands, just shows them.

Comment: seem VERBOSE=1 -n work with me. Thanks :)